# How to count One2many field in report template odoo 15

Tags: python, report, one2many, odoo-15

Can some one tell me how to count One2many field in report template please?

I've a One2many field called `calendar_jobs_ids`
I want to count it and print to my report template, but i don't know how to do it.

[image]

Can some one help me please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, that we call function from model to count the One2many field, then we use it in report template, that'll be good.

[image]

[image]